# iOS change view with tab bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am a beginner in programming in iOS. I have a iOS application that has two classes(with xib), firstviewcontroller and secondviewcontroller. I want to add a tab bar to switch between these view controllers. if I for example add a tab bar to the first view, how to connect the views to the tab bar? Its just there, doing nothing..

Comment: can you post some code? Or if you set up the tab bar using interface builder, a screenshot of the xibs?

Answer (score 2):

Try Look into this url , this will help.
http://www.amateurinmotion.com/articles/2009/01/24/creating-uitabbarcontroller-based-app-using-interfacebuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you want the tab bar as the main interface of your app.

- In your app delegate, create a subclass of `UITabBarController`:

  `UITabBarController *myTbc = [UITabBarController alloc] init];`
- Create instances of your two view controllers and add them to an `NSArray`

  `NSArray *tabsArray = @[firstVC, secondVC];`
- Set that NSArray as the `viewControllers` property of the tab bar controller

  `[myTbc setViewControllers:tabsArray];`
- Set the tab bar controller as the app's root view:

  `self.window.rootViewController = theTbc;`